# Failed to create feature receiver object from assembly/FileNotFound

Tags: sharepoint

During solution deployments & Feature activation, I am facing an on/off issue where the system is unable to find & load the FeatureReceiver class. Mostly it is file not found exception (even though the assembly is there in the GAC). I checked over the net and this seems it a common issue with solutions (wsp) packaging DLL to be GACed. (But, no one has any clue or solution!)
What is the recommendation and guideline to fix this issue? We are setting the flag to reset IIS in my solution definition - but that does not seem to help. The issue is more prevalent in multi-M farms.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a general problem in SharePoint in cause of the "SharePoint 2010 Timer Service". Because this one caches the wsp's and during the deployment or feature activation old references will occurres this error!

So try the following link. I hope this solution will help you.

http://msscorner.de/en/2011/10/27/sharepoint-deployment-failed-to-create-receiver-object-from-assembly/

Comment: Short version - don't forget to restart the SharePoint 2010 Timer service!

Answer (score 3):

First try the solution linked to by Falco...
If that does not help, try this:

1. Open the event-receiver file created by sharepoint
2. Compare the GUID above the `event-receiver-class` with the one stated in the stack-trace "...class=7g3562-438dn4...
3. If it does not match:

   - Copy the content of the class
   - Delete the file
   - Create a new file by right-clicking the feature -> add new event reciever
   - Pass the content

Comment: My GUID did match however I followed step 3 just in case it was reading the GUID from the class and printing it out in the error and it looks like this is the case as my feature has now deployed. +1'd

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you dont need to give iisreset as your wsp deployment would have already done that.

Can you check if the assembly name, version, public token specified in the feature.xml is same at the actual assembly that is deployed in gac? I am thinking there is mismatch in assembly signature